# Smart Screen filter warning: "Are you trying to visit this website?"

Tags: internet-explorer, web, microsoft-edge

I uploaded my website to the internet few days ago. My site works fine on Chrome, but on IE and edge browsers, I get a warning from Smart Screen. In IE, it says:

"Are you trying to visit this website?
SmartScreen filter helps protect you from unsafe website that impersonate addresses or content from legitimate websites.
You can help SmartScreen filter identify unsafe websites by providing your feedback below."

I had an option to report the site as safe- and that's what I did. But 3 days passed and nothing changed. I also tried to google it, and I found the following link, when someone who had similar problem to mine talked to Microsoft support and they fixed it (check RB2251 comment at February 11, 2016 4:04 AM):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15649efb-586e-45e6-962c-067921656f2c/smartscreen-filter-warning-on-my-web-sites?forum=ieitprocurrentver

But after 2 days that I am talking with Microsoft support, they didn't solved my problem yet.
Is there another way to pass this SmartScreen filter?
In every day that passes, people are accessing to my web and sees this warning- and probably some of them won't come back because of it.
I saw that I can turn off this filter on my computer, but I want this warning will also not appear in other people's computer, when entering my site...

**Edit:** I have a problem of putting my site URL here, but I will show you an image of the warning I get from SmartScreen filter (I get it on every page on my website):

[a busy cat http://www.interload.co.il/upload/2892919.jpg](http://www.interload.co.il/upload/2892919.jpg)

Comment: Are you allowed to post the URL of your web site here? That might help someone figure out the problem.

Comment: Right know, I can't do it. However, I now edited the post so that you can see an image of the warning that I get

Comment: Obviously, without seeing your site, we cannot really help you... Maybe, you are doing an unsafe site but you don't want us to know that...

Comment: Phil, it doesn't relevant anymore- check my answer that was posted before your response. My site was confirmed as safe, the warning was removed, and no URL was needed to be provided for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested- this is how I solved it eventually:

From another search on google, I saw that it might help if other people entering your site from their computer approve the site as safe, in addition to you (the site owner) off course. So I talked to few firends of mine, and asked them to enter the site and just confirm in the warning text box that the site is safe on IE and edge browsers.
Today, after less then 12 hours from the time I asked my friends to enter the site and confirm it as safe- the warning was gone.

I can't tell for sure that it really what solved the problem, but I'll tell you this:
When I first saw the warning text box, I approved the site as safe. 5 days passed since then, including a lot of talks with Microsoft technical support- and nothing changed.
And as you can see above, less then 12 hours after my friends approved the site as safe- problem solved.